# spark dataframe sum of column based on condition

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I want to calculate the portion of the value, with only two partitions( where type == red and where type != red)

```
ID     | type        | value
-----------------------------
  1    |    red      |  10
  2    |    blue     |  20
  3    |    yellow   |  30
```

result should be :

```
ID     | type        | value | portion
-----------------------------
  1    |    red      |  10   | 1
  2    |    blue     |  20   |0.4
  3    |    yellow   |  30   |0.6
```

The normal window function in spark only supports partitionby a whole column, but I need the "blue" and "yellow", together recognized as the "non-red" type.

Any idea?

Comment: The blue/yellow ratio over non-red may need to be done in a separate step. But have you tried using an additional column (like `is_red`) or an sql `case`?

Comment: are you trying to do this only with `spark-sql`? you could do this in multiple operations pretty easily in `spark`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add a column `is_red` to easier differentiate between the two groups. Then you can `groupBy` this new column and get the sums for each of the two groups respectively.

To get the fraction (portion), simply divide each row's value by the correct sum, taking into account if the type is red or not. This part can be done using `when` and `otherwise` in Spark.

Below is the Scala code to do this. There is a `sortBy` since when using `groupBy` the order of results is not guaranteed. With the sort, `sum1` below will contain the total sum for all non-red types while `sum2` is the sum for red types.

```
val sum1 :: sum2 :: _ = df.withColumn("is_red", $"type" === lit("red"))
  .groupBy($"is_red")
  .agg(sum($"value"))
  .collect()
  .map(row => (row.getAs[Boolean](0), row.getAs[Long](1)))
  .toList
  .sortBy(_._1)
  .map(_._2)

val df2 = df.withColumn("portion", when($"is_red", $"value"/lit(sum2)).otherwise($"value"/lit(sum1)))
```

The extra `is_red` column can be removed using `drop`.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Shaido, I used an extra column `is_red` and the spark window function. But I'm not sure which one is better in performance.

```
 df.withColumn("is_red", when(col("type").equalTo("Red"), "Red")
   .otherwise("not Red")
   .withColumn("portion", col("value")/sum("value)
   .over(Window.partitionBy(col"is_Red")))
   .drop(is_Red)
```